# Why is there current flowing into my JFET?

Tags: jfet, biasing

When I connect my JFET to a 9 volt battery and then short circuit the gate to the source via an ammmeter, it reads 6 mA of current. When I try biasing the JFET ([BFW 11](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/77366/MOTOROLA/BFW11.html)) with a 1 MΩ resistor the current going into the gate causes a voltage drop across the resistor and prevents correct biasing.

Why is this?

[image]

When I measure the voltage drop across the 1 MΩ resistor I get a reading of around 7 volts.

When I short circuit the gate to the source with an ammmeter I get a reading of around 6 mA.

[image]

[image]

---

**Amendment** - added drawing showing 4th pin on the JFET.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how your red battery lead connects to the JFET please. You should draw a small circuit diagram.

Comment: I have added the circuit

Comment: I'll ask again... can you explain how your red battery lead connects to the JFET please.

Comment: The red lead connects to the drain of the JFET. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Please don't amend your answer with the new diagram as you have. Add the new diagram as a clear amendment at the bottom of your answer. I shall do this for you in case someone stumbling across this Q and A thinks I was too stupid to notice your added drawing.

Comment: Since the datasheet may be wrong, you can find the gate with the diode test function of a multimeter. It must behave like a normal diode to both ends of the channel, drain and source. The channel between drain and source behaves like a resistor below 1 kohm if you touch all pins with a finger to remove gate charges. It is not so easy to find out which pin is source and which is drain, but for your test circuit this should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The red lead connects to the drain of the JFET*

Not as far as I can see: -

[image]

As far as I can tell from your picture there is nothing connected to the red wire. And also, one pin of your JFET appears to be floating in mid air (JFET #2).

> *There is a fourth lead at the back tot visible in the picture –  LEXOR
> AI*

From the data sheet you linked you may have mis-wired the JFET due to an error in the diagrams: -

[image]

Drain and gate are incorrectly designated.

Comment: There is a fourth lead at the back not visible in the picture. The pin that is floating in mid air is not used. See datasheet

Comment: I am aware of this error in the diagram. My circuit is connected correctly as in this datasheet:https://www.web-bcs.com/transistor/tfet/ba/BFW11.php     I have added another picture from the side perspective as well.

Comment: @LEXORAI OK, now that we have cleared all that up, what is it about your measurements that concerns you. They appear to be correct for a JFET.

Comment: I want to bias the jfet with the 1 MOhm resistor like a pull down resistor so that the gate to source voltage becomes negative. For this to happen the Gate voltage should be zero but there is current flowing into the gate which causes a voltage drop across the 1 Mohm resistor. There should be no current flowing into the gate?

Comment: Well, it's either a faulty device, an incorrect device or, you have incorrectly wired it @LEXORAI

Comment: Well from my picture I assume you can see it is correctly wired? In what way could it be faulty it is a newly bought JFET?

Comment: I can't answer that other than to ask where did you buy it from.

Comment: I bought it from a local electronics shop. So you agree that this measurements should not be happening assuming it were not faulty?

Comment: Yes I would and also that you have wired it correctly. Given the data sheet error, this possibility is still under suspicion. Have you tried swapping pins 2 and 3 to try this out?

Comment: Have you looked at the othere datasheet? The drain is on the top opposite of the notch, the source is at the bottom and the gate is wired to the 1MOhm resistor. The left out pin is not used. Given this information and the second datasheet I have provided could you not determine if I have wired it correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at this datasheet though? https://www.web-bcs.com/transistor/tfet/ba/BFW11.php

Comment: The pins on the datasheet are all labeled incorrectly not only pin 1 and 2. Even the source is incorrect

Comment: I'm just saying; try it out or get a new JFET.

Comment: Tried it again does not work

Comment: Buy a new one is my advice.

Comment: I will buy a new one and see if the problem fixes itself

Comment: Make sure you handle with care because the gate-source junction is susceptible to static discharge problems.

Comment: Your selected Jfet must be 60 years old. Why not buy a modern one that has neat inline 3 pins and is in an epoxy package? The breadboard hides most of your wiring, why not solder the parts compactly and neatly on a stripboard?

Comment: Which JFET would be appropriate for a microphone capsule to be connected with directly for impedance matching? That is why I used this specific one.

Comment: @LEXORAI If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.